# JavaScript & Selenium WebDriver

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Selenium WebDriver and trying to access Web Elements. I'm on a webpage which is developed as JSP pages and somehow I'm unable to access a Element which is inside a  tag. These pages get loaded as HTML pages. I will try to share test code soon.

Comment: I'm still have problems with telepathy. How about to show some code?

Comment: Thanks @Aleks Andreev. As I said I will share the Code soon. May be tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

Please use locators to identify the element. You can use id, class name ,xpath etc to identify the element.

One important thing is that your DOM should be ready before you find your element .  Use web driver wait till element is prepared.

Please share sample code to give the correct solution

Comment: Thanks Narasimha...I will share the code tomorrow...I don't have it right now. Will share the same from office...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all...I understand that my 1st query was not upto the mark...I just created my account yesterday and am a Newbie...

Anyway, thanks to those who helped and took time to read the query.

I have was able to resolve the query by switching the Focus to the iFrame as follows:

```
    List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));
    // print your number of frames
    System.out.println(iframes.size());

    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    Thread.sleep(2000);

    if (isElementPresent(By.xpath("(//input[@name='command'])[2]")))
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='command'])[2]")).click();
```

Thanks again...